# Testing a link's target attribute with Capybara/RSpec

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm a bit new to Rails/RSpec/Capybara, so this is probably a newbie question, but Google didn't help as much as I would have hoped. I was hoping that I could use

```
it { should have_link('link text', href: 'url', target: '_blank') }
```

to write a test for a link that should open in a new window, but that doesn't seem to work.  I've also tried wrapping the options hash in curly-braces:

```
it { should have_link('link text', {href: 'url', target: '_blank'}) }
```

The test will always succeed regardless of the presence or value of the target attribute in the actual page and link being tested.  Changing the href attribute does cause a test failure as expected.  I thought the options hash for have_link was a list of attributes to test for. Apparently I'm wrong, but what's the best way to test a single link for it's target attribute?  Hopefully it's not to use an XPath search...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I am not sure why your code does not work. Have you tried this:

```
find_link('link_text')[:href].should == 'url'
find_link('link_text')[:target].should == '_blank'
```

Answer (score 13):

Using new rspec 3 syntax:

```
is_expected.to have_link('link_text', href: 'url')
expect(find_link('link_text')[:target]).to eq('_blank')
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
it { should have_css "a[href~='/somewhere'][target~='_blank']" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a custom matcher that finds the link and checks its `target` attribute is `'_blank'`:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_link_open_in_new_window do |locator, options={}|
  match do |page|
    link = page.find_link(locator, options)
    link && link[:target] == '_blank'
  end
end
```

Use `have_link_open_in_new_window(locator, options)` as you'd use `have_link(locator, options)`:

```
expect(page).to have_link_open_in_new_window('Link text or id', href: '...')
```